# What are the following instructions after this call (assembly)

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm currently analyzing a piece of malware.  I've identified several types of shells, this one specifically is an icmp shell.  In the screenshot below, you can see the value at 0x804af87 pushed onto the stack, which is 'icmp'.  This is to satisfy the '**char** *name' in getprotobyname.

[image: icmp_shell asm screenshot]

However, after that call is made, there are a few instructions that don't make sense to me.  I understand the instructions themselves but I'm failing to understand as to what they may be doing in regards to this icmp shell.

For example, 0x10 is immediately added to the stack pointer after the **getprotobyname** call.  What is the purpose of this?  And sequentially the instructions that follow.

Comment: Pushing args on the stack decrements the stack pointer. Incrementing the stack pointer removes the args. That's what's happening here. You can see a `sub esp, 12`, which is allocating 12 stack bytes, probably to align the stack frame. Then there's a push that subtracts 4 more.  The total is 16. That's what the `add` is removing. The next instruction is storing the function return value into a stack variable.  You need to read up on the ABI / calling convention of your os and processor.

Comment: Post code *as code*, please! Don't post an image of code. If you can copy-paste, great. If not, that means you have to retype it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code you're analyzing, in text form:

```
mov   DWORD PTR [ebp-0x1c], 0x1f90
sub   esp, 0xc
push  0x804af87
call  0x8048cc0 <getprotobyname@plt>
add   esp, 0x10
mov   DWORD PTR [ebp-0x102c], eax
sub   esp, 0x4
mov   eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-0x102c]
```

Let's look at this one instruction at a time, to make sure we understand what they're doing:

1. `mov  DWORD PTR [ebp-0x1c], 0x1f90`

   This stores the constant `0x1f90` on the stack, specifically at the location `ebp-0x1c`, which is 28 bytes behind the current base pointer (`ebp`).
2. `sub  esp, 0xc`

   This subtracts 12 bytes from the stack pointer (`esp`), which essentially allocates some space on the stack. You will either do this because you need to store some data there, or because you're about to make a function call under an ABI that requires a particular alignment (such as [the System V ABI for x86](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI)).
3. `push  0x804af87`

   This pushes the constant value `0x804af87` onto the stack, which implicitly decrements the stack pointer by 4 more bytes and stores the value there.

   This is very likely done in preparation for a function call, since many x86 calling conventions pass arguments on the stack.
4. `call  0x8048cc0 <getprotobyname@plt>`

   This calls the `getprotobyname` function, at the absolute address `0x8048cc0`.
5. `add  esp, 0x10`

   This adds 16 bytes to the stack pointer (`esp`), which cleans up the space that we previously made on the stack. Recall that we had previously decremented the stack pointer by 12 bytes, and then pushed a 4-byte value onto the stack, for a total of 16 bytes. This instruction effectively "undoes" that, freeing up the stack space that we no longer need.

   Some calling conventions require the *caller* to clean up the stack after a function call; clearly, this code is using such a calling convention.
6. `mov  DWORD PTR [ebp-0x102c], eax`

   In this code's calling convention, the function's return value is stored in the `eax` register. (This is true for all integer-sized return values in all x86 calling conventions that I know of.) Therefore, the result of the `getprotobyname` function (in `eax`) will be stored in memory, at the location `ebp-0x102c`, which is 4140 bytes behind the current base pointer (`ebp`).
7. `sub  esp, 0x4`

   This subtracts 4 bytes from the stack pointer, effectively allocating 4 bytes of storage space on the stack.
8. `mov  eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-0x102c]`

   This retrieves the value in memory, at the location `ebp-0x102c`, and stores it in the `eax` register.

Now that we understand what's happening here, it should be obvious that this is sub-optimal code and several of these instructions are redundant/superfluous.

In particular, the `getprotobyname` function's return value starts out in `eax`, is stored to memory, and is then retrieved from memory and placed back into `eax`. None of that is necessary. All of those instructions can be eliminated.

Furthermore, adding 16 bytes to the stack pointer and then subtracting 4 bytes from the stack pointer is the same as adding 12 bytes to the stack pointer. Thus, these `add` and `sub` instructions could be combined into one. There is no apparent reason for making them separate instructions.

I would guess either that this is *unoptimized* code that you're looking at (such as might be generated by a C compiler with optimizations disabled), or that this has been done intentionally by the programmer for padding (instead of inserting `nop` instructions).

A more optimal (and more sane) version of the code would be as follows:

```
mov   DWORD PTR [ebp-0x1c], 0x1f90     ; store value in memory
sub   esp, 0xc                         ; allocate 12 bytes of stack space
push  0x804af87                        ; push function argument
call  0x8048cc0 <getprotobyname@plt>   ; call function
add   esp, 0xc                         ; clean up stack space
; function's return value is now in EAX—use as desired
; ...
; if you like, store it in memory:
; mov   DWORD PTR [ebp-0x102c], eax
```

As suggested by Gene in a comment, do be sure to inform yourself of the standard x86 calling conventions—in particular, the `__cdecl` calling convention. Detailed information can be found in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.

Comment: As another answer pointed out, `sub  esp, 0xc` is to align the stack before `call`, as required by the ABI.  https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI.  Nothing uses that space, it's just alignment.

Comment: @Peter Which ABI is that? I'm not familiar with the notation "ps" or with that GitHub repository you linked. Alignment was what I had in mind what the phrase *"or because you're about to make a function call that requires it"*, but I guess that could have been more clear. There wasn't enough information in the question that I felt comfortable assuming a particular ABI was in effect. There are a number of them to choose from now.

Comment: That's the i386 **P**rocessor **S**upplement to the  System V ABI.  Most people would say "the i386 SysV ABI", but technically there's a generic ABI document that lays out some arch-independent stuff, and the actually alignment rules are filled in by the "processor supplement" for x86-64, i386, ARM, or whatever. That URL has links to PDF copies of the current versions as used by Linux.

Comment: As far as what ABI the OP is using, we can be confident it's not Windows, because the `call` is going through the PLT.  Windows DLLs don't use a PLT.  So it's a good bet that it's either Linux or OS X.  32-bit OS X might not actually require 16B stack alignment, because they might still be using an older revision of the SysV ABI.  (And of course the kernel system call convention is different from Linux, but the i386 psABI doc leave it unspecified, unlike for x86-64)

Answer (score 1):

```
sub   esp, 0xc
push  0x804af87
call  0x8048cc0 <getprotobyname@plt>
add   esp, 0x10
```

> This subtracts 12 bytes from the stack pointer (esp), which essentially allocates some space on the stack. You will either do this because you need to store some data there, or because you're about to make a function call that requires it.

For the instruction, it is NOT used to preserve some temporary space, it in fact is used for stack alignment (refer to [here](http://blog.opensecurityresearch.com/2013/06/reversing-basics-part-2-understanding.html)).

According to the manual of gcc: -mpreferred-stack-boundary=num => Attempt to keep the stack boundary aligned to a 2 raised to num byte boundary.  If -mpreferred-stack-boundary is not specified, the default is 4 (16 bytes or 128 bits).

So if you append "-mpreferred-stack-boundary=2, 3, or 4" on your gcc command line, then you will get the different asm generation, which will demonstrate the compiler stack alignment problem.

Comment: The current i386 System V ABI requires 16B alignment before `call`, so lowering `-mpreferred-stack-boundary` breaks the ABI.  It's no longer just a performance boost, functions are allowed to crash if called with misaligned stacks (although most don't).  https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.